# How to ensure div doesn't close once it is opened unless the page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a map with dots. When you click each dot, it opens up a `<div>` with a form related to that dot.

Once you click the dot and the `<div>` opens, when you click a different dot it closes that `<div>` and the new form related to the recently clicked dot opens in `<div>`.

How can I have the `<div>` open once and never close unless the page is refreshed?

[Here is the code](http://pastebin.com/a3Ad4xQB)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".dot").show();

    $('.dot').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
    });

});

</script>

<script>
jQuery(function(){
         $('#showSingle').click(function(){
               $('.targetDiv').show();
        });
        $('.dot').click(function(){
              $('.targetDiv').hide();
              $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried removing `$('.targetDiv').hide();` from line 22?

Comment: `jQuery(function(){` does the same thing as `$(document).ready(function(){` so I'd recommend putting everything into ONE of those, as well as combining the two separate `$('.dot').click(function(){` declarations. Makes it easier to read/diagnose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first select a dot, the information appears. But when you select a different dot (or even the same one), the information box closes. This is because you are using [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/). You want to use [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) and `slideUp()`, because `slideToggle` will toggle it show/hidden depending on its current state.

I'm assuming if the user selects the already opened dot, you want to hide the information. The following code takes care of that by using [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to determine if the selected dot also has the class of `selected`.

```
$('.dot').click(function(){
   //$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
   if ($(this).hasClass("selected") {
       $(".slidingDiv").slideUp('slow');
   }
   else {
       $(".slidingDiv").slideDown('slow');
   }
});
```

-Read more about [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

Comment: Yes I tired to remove it and didn't work.. but think I need to show you the whole page so you get a better idea. the actual map pic isn't working but you can see what I'm doing http://terrytilley.com/stackoverflow/

Comment: @TerryT Changed my answer. Did I correctly identify your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a separate class for dots that will open a div but will not close a target div, then just use that new class when assigning a click handler:

```
$('.dot2').click(function(){
    $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

Comment: http://terrytilley.com/stackoverflow/ this how it looks (actual map pic is not working) you can see what I'm trying to do.